# How to overwrite .mdf file

Tags: c#, sql-server, nunit, localdb

I am working on a project which involves using a database and I am unit testing it. Right now the tests create a database as a `.mdf` file and use it.

What I want to do is to make a copy of this `.mdf` file somewhere else and before each test replace the original `.mdf` file with the copy I had just made. The problem is that when I try to do so, it says that the file is being used by another process. I found out that process is `sqlservr.exe`.

My question is: is there any way to stop the server from using the file so I can replace it? I have tried the SQL Server BACKUP and RESTORE options, but they are not good enough for me because they slow down the process way too much.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so a little more information on the problem. Basically I am working with improving performance of my unit tests. Most of the tests require a connection to a database, so I have a LocalDb in a `.mdf` file. This file is created during the `TestFixtureSetup`. Then, before each test (during the `SetUp`) the database is wiped via SQL commands. It seems to be not the most efficient way of recreating a fresh database for each test. So I have tried two different methods as of now:

1. Use SQL BACKUP and RESTORE commands. This works, but it increases the execution time of my tests.
2. Killing the `sqlservr.exe` process, locally copying the file and restarting `sqlservr.exe`. This also works, but increases the execution time as well.

So basically I am looking for suggestions on how to improve the performance of recreating a completely empty database.

Comment: Stop the service, copy, then start again?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187858.aspx Detach might work then Attach it back

Answer (score 2):

- You can stop the service, copy the `.MDF` file and restart the service
- You can also detach the database, copy it, and re-attach it again
- You can also backup the database

**Update:**

To start, stop, pause, resume, or restart SQL Server Browser or an instance of SQL Server Agent.

Start the SQL Server Configuration Manager by following the instructions above.
If the dialog box User Account Control appears, click Yes.

In the SQL Server Configuration Manager, in the left pane, click SQL Server Services .

In the results pane, right-click SQL Server Browser, SQL Server Agent (`MSSQLServer`) , or SQL Server Agent () for a named instance,

Then click Start, Stop, Pause, Resume, or Restart.

Click OK to close the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

**Update :**

[image: See This Pic]

Comment: Is there a faster way of doing this backup? Because I tried killing the process, copying the files and then starting the process again, but it actually takes more time than before.

Comment: @vstrimaitis in the popup menu click "Stop"

Comment: I understand this part, but I need to do this programatically (in my code: make a backup of my .mdf file, do some work, replace the original .mdf file with the copy, repeat)

Comment: @vstrimaitis you should audate your Q.